# Making (and edit existing) posts with ID included

Tags: php, posts, id

I've got lots of posts with the same title (home estate's properties), and i need to make url of single property -> title + ID (id part, adde automatically) after making new post.

And is it possible to change existing one's? (i've got lots of them already created)

Please help, i'm stuck

Comment: please share a code you're working on

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is actually what Wordpress does automatically for you.

Navigate to ***Settings>Permalinks*** and add your custom structure you want like:

```
/%postname%-%post_id%/
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will update post url when you save it:

```
function wpse_288020_replace_url( $post_id ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    if( $post_type === 'your_post_type' ) {

        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $title = sanitize_title( $title );

        $post = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_name' => sprintf('%s-%s', $title, $post_id),
        );

        remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_288020_replace_url' ); // Remove action to prevent loop

        wp_update_post( $post );

        add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_288020_replace_url' );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_288020_replace_url' );
```

And this code will make mass update of all your posts urls:

```
function wpse_288020_batch_replace_url() {

    // Get all posts
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));

    $posts = $query->get_posts();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        // Get permalink
        $title = sanitize_title($post->post_title);

        // Prepare arguments
        $args = array(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_name' => sprintf('%s-%s', $title, $post->ID),
        );

        // Update post
        wp_update_post( $args );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'wpse_288020_batch_replace_url');
```

If you have many posts disable creating revision posts by adding `WP_POST_REVISIONS` constant to `wp-config.php`. It will speed up script and reduce the demand for memory usage.

`define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );`